# What is cloudant size restrictons

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I didn't find in bluemix documentation cloudant size restrictions.

What is size restrictions of document, attachment or database in cloudant?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of an individual JSON document is 1 MB. There are some more metrics in [this table in the Cloudant Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/offerings/bluemix.html#maximum-individual-document-size). The maximum database size is not specified, but there are different storage plans.